# IIS 7 replication of web site

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, load-balancing

Is there any way to replicate website on different servers for load balancing so that some of the requests are served from one server and the others from other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you at least Google for an answer? This subject is well documented all over the web. For a start, check out [HTTP Load Balancing using Application Request Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/486/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing/) on [iis.net](http://www.iis.net/) (excellent source for anything related to IIS anyway). The blog post [IIS7 Load Balancing & Routing Module Now Available!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/02/17/iis7-load-balancing-routing-module-now-available.aspx) on MSDN also contains a lot of useful links. Instead of ARR you can also use pretty much any kind of load balancer (e.g. [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)).

To make the same content available to all servers in your farm you can simply use a Windows based file server or any kind of NAS with SMB file sharing. IIS allows you to specify the credentials that will be used when connecting to the file share.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there are heaps of solutions for doing this. The one that Stackoverflow use is called HAProxy http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

Typically what you need is a form of reverse proxy that can pipe your requests to the various servers it knows about.

As an aside - Interesting link about SO architecture. http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is Web Farm Framework http://www.iis.net/download/WebFarmFramework